Help understanding the difference between solving inequalities when squaring them
Just wanted help understanding what is the fundamental difference between these following 2 ways of solving the inequality:
$$
2-\sqrt{x-1} < 1
$$
When I went on to solve it like:
$-\sqrt{x-1} < -1 \therefore (-\sqrt{x-1})^2< (-1)^2 \therefore x-1 < 1 \therefore x < 2$ 
I know that the correct way of solving it would be $-\sqrt{x-1} < -1 \therefore 1 < \sqrt{x-1} \therefore 1 < x-1 \therefore 2 < x$, but I can't see why the first one is wrong.
Thx

Hint: When is $ a^2 < b^2$? Is it only if $ a < b$?

How do you go from $-\sqrt{x-1}<-1$ to $\left(-\sqrt{x-1}\right)^2<(-1)^2$?

If you multiply by a negative number it reverses the direction of the inequality. Here when you go from $-1$ to $(-1)^2$ you're multiplying by a negative. So that step is wrong.

To solve the inequality $ 2 - \sqrt{x - 1} < 1 $, we will first isolate the square root on one side.
Start by subtracting $2$ from both sides:
$
-\sqrt{x - 1} < -1
$
Next, multiply both sides by -1, remembering to reverse the inequality:
$
\sqrt{x - 1} > 1
$
Now, we will square both sides (since both sides are non-negative):
$
x - 1 > 1^2
$
$
\implies x - 1 > 1
$
$
\implies x > 2
$
Thus, the solution to the inequality $ 2 - \sqrt{x - 1} < 1 $ is:
$
\boxed{x > 2}
$
